# Change drives in Mac startup manager to display "Macintosh HD" instead of "EFI Boot"

Tags: partition, mac-pro, efi

I have a Mac Pro 3,1 running Catalina (patched by dosdude1's installer to work on my unsupported Mac). Initially, I was having problems with my GPU which led me to install OpenCore as per the suggestion of a forum user. I ended up solving my GPU problem without OpenCore so I formatted my partition (to APFS) and installed Catalina normally.

Currently I have Windows installed on another partition. My drives are as follows:

Physical disk 1: 
Macintosh HD (Contains OS)
Windows HD (Contains OS)

Physical disk 2: 
Windows HD 2 (No OS, for extra storage)

Physical disk 3:
Macintosh HD 2 (for extra storage, formatted APFS)
Windows HD 3 (for extra storage)

When I boot my Mac holding the Option key, I see:

"Windows"   "EFI Boot"   "EFI Boot"

Windows boots up Windows 10. Both EFI boot options boot up Catalina and I have no idea why they display this way.

In Startup Disk on Catalina, I see "Mac OS" and "Windows HD", which is exactly what I would expect my boot loader to look like.

In Startup Disk on Windows 10, I see "Windows HD", "Basic data partition Windows" and another "Basic Partition Windows". If I click any of the latter two, it boots up in Catalina.

Comment: In your title, does "Mac boot loader" mean "Mac Startup Manager"?

Comment: Does "holding the Control key" really mean "holding the option key"?

Comment: The last two paragraphs in your question seem to contradict each other.  Both start with "In startup disk on Catalina, I see".

Comment: My bad, I wrote this late last night and didn't review it. I've edited correctly to reflect my problem. Thank you for pointing this out!